# Mathematically, why does this SICP algorithm for the exponent of a number modulo another number work?

Tags: scheme, sicp, exponentiation, modular-arithmetic

[Section 1.2.6 of SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#call_footnote_Temp_77) gives the following procedure:

```
    (define (expmod base exp m)
  (cond ((= exp 0) 1)
        ((even? exp)
         (remainder (square (expmod base (/ exp 2) m))
                    m))
        (else
         (remainder (* base (expmod base (- exp 1) m))
                    m))))
```

The authors claim that it "*computes the exponential of a number modulo another number*". For example `(expmod 5 3 n)` should return (5^3) mod n.

However, from a mathematical point of view, I just can't see how it works. As reinforced by [footnote 46](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#footnote_Temp_78), it is intended to use the property that for any positive integers a, b, and n, (ab) mod n = [(a mod n)(b mod n)] mod n, but I fail to see how it is actually using it. Consider `(expmod 5 3 3)`:

1. First, we call `(expmod 5 3 3)`. Mathematically, this means that we're asking for (5^3) mod 3.
2. As the second parameter is odd, we compute `(remainder (* 5 (expmod 5 (- 3 1) 3)) 3)` i.e. `(remainder (* 5 (expmod 5 2 3)) 3)`. Mathematically, this is [5 * [(5^2) mod 3]] mod 3. As the initial 5 in this expression does not have a mod 3 attached, this expression is **not** in the (ab) mod n = [(a mod n)(b mod n)] mod n form, so it fails to use the intended property.

So, given that this it appears to not be using the intended property, why does this algorithm work? What property of modular arithmetic have I overlooked?

Comment: Regarding point 2, note that (a * (b mod n)) mod n is *also* equal to (a * b) mod n.

Comment: @molbdnilo Strange, if something that nice was true, I would have expected it to be front and centre in [Wikipedia's list of properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Properties_(identities)). Have I missed it?

Comment: It follows trivially from the addition rule. (Most of the things worth knowing are not mentioned in Wikipedia at all.)

Comment: @molbdnilo From the addition rule? If it's trivial, I can't see it so easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the definition of fast-exp from 1.2.4 that is refered to:

```
(define (fast-expt b n)
  (cond ((= n 0) 1)
        ((even? n) (square (fast-expt b (/ n 2))))
        (else (* b (fast-expt b (- n 1))))))
```

If we rename things to closer match expmod it looks like this:

```
(define (expt base exp)
  (cond ((= exp 0) 1)
        ((even? exp)
         (square (expt base (/ exp 2))))
        (else
         (* base (expt base (- exp 1))))))
```

To get a naive `expmod` we can, for now, just calculate the remainder of each clause:

```
(define (expmod base exp m)
  (cond ((= exp 0) 1)
        ((even? exp)
         (remainder (square (expt base (/ exp 2))) m))
        (else
         (remainder (* base (expt base (- exp 1))) m))
```

So far we have not used the footnote `(ab) mod m = ((a mod m)(b mod m) mod m)`.  Of course a special case of this is `(aa) mod m =  ((a mod m)(a mod m) mod m)` which gives `(remainder (square a) m) = (remainder (sqaure (remainder a m)) m)`.  We can use this with the `even` clause so that

```
         (remainder (square (expt base (/ exp 2))) m)
```

becomes:

```
         (remainder (square (remainder (expt base (/ exp 2)) m))
                    m)
```

In the middle of this we have the remainder of an exponent so this is equivalent to:

```
         (remainder (square (expmod base (/ exp 2) m)) m)
```

Using the new `even` clause we have

```
(define (expmod base exp m)
  (cond ((= exp 0) 1)
        ((even? exp)
         (remainder (square (expmod base (/ exp 2) m)) 
                    m))
        (else
         (remainder (* base (expt base (- exp 1))) m))
```

To simplify the odd clause lets use `E` in place of `(expt base (- exp 1))` for now.

By using the defining properties of `mod` we can say for any number `a`:

```
         a = (+ (* (quotient a m) m) (remainder a m))
```

So it's also true that:

```
         E = (+ (* (quotient E m) m) (remainder E m))
```

substituting this into our `odd` clause:

```
         (remainder (* base E) m)
```

gives:

```
         (remainder (* base (+ (* (quotient E m) m) (remainder E m))) m)
```

We can ignore  `(* (quotient E m) m)` because any term containg this is divisible by `m` and so will evaluate to `0` when doing the outer `remainder`, so this equivalent to:

```
         (remainder (* base (remainder E m)) m)
```

expanding E to it's orignal value:

```
         (remainder (* base (remainder (expt base (- exp 1)) m)) m)
```

once again, in the middle, we have the remainder of an exponent so this becomes:

```
         (remainder (* base (expmod base (- exp 1) m)) m)
```

And our `expmod` is now:

```
(define (expmod base exp m)
  (cond ((= exp 0) 1)
        ((even? exp)
         (remainder (square (expmod base (/ exp 2) m)) 
                    m))
        (else
         (remainder (* base (expmod base (- exp 1) m))
                    m))))
```

Comment: So, ultimately, the odd branch does not use the property in question?

Comment: `(remainder (* base (remainder E m)) m)` appears to be of the form [a*(b mod m)] mod m. As this was derived from `(remainder (* base E) m)`, am I correct to conclude that you've given a proof of the same property that Sorawee Porncharoenwase has? i.e. (ab) mod n = [a (b mod n)] mod n?

Comment: @J.Mini That's right I didn't use it in the odd clause.  There might be a way to use it when eliminating `(* (quotient E m) m)` but I'm not smart enough to see it, and in any case it seems a little contrived.  I didn't look at Sorawee's answer closely, was busy writing my own :-), perhaps I'd say this answer builds on his?

Answer (score 1):

```
(ab) mod n = [a (b mod n)] mod n
```

is also true.

Here's a proof by induction on `a`.

Base case: when `a = 0`, `(0b) mod n = 0 mod n = [0 (b mod n)] mod n`.

Inductive case:

By induction hypothesis, assume that `(ab) mod n = [a (b mod n)] mod n` is true. We need to prove that `((a+1) b) mod n = [(a + 1) (b mod n)] mod n`.

```
((a+1) b) mod n
= (ab + b) mod n
= (ab mod n) + (b mod n)
= [a (b mod n)] mod n + (b mod n)             by induction hypothesis
= [a (b mod n)] mod n + (b mod n) mod n
= [a (b mod n) + (b mod n)] mod n
= [(a + 1) (b mod n)] mod n
```

as desired.

This concludes the proof that

```
(ab) mod n = [a (b mod n)] mod n
```

---

In fact, you can see that

```
(ab) mod n = [(a mod n) (b mod n)] mod n
```

is a result that follows from it. Here's a proof:

```
(ab) mod n 
= [a (b mod n)] mod n            by what we just proved
= [(b mod n) a] mod n
= [(b mod n) (a mod n)] mod n    by what we just proved
= [(a mod n) (b mod n)] mod n
```

Comment: I'm surprised that this wasn't [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Properties_(identities)). The version that you've proven is stronger than the one that they give. Why would they give a specific case when there is a more powerful version that requires no additional concepts? Moreover, I'm surprised that it wasn't in SICP's footnote. It makes me wonder if I misread it. Did I?

Comment: Well, Wikipedia doesn't contain everything, Also, there's nothing wrong with `[(a mod n) (b mod n)] mod n`. One could argue that it's SICP's mistake that they didn't follow the equation accurately, and the fix is to use `(* (remainder base m) ...)` instead of `(* base ...)`. In fact, from performance's point of view, it's better to use `(* (remainder base m) ...)`. See [my PR](https://github.com/racket/math/pull/52) to improve the performance of `modular-expt` in Racket, for example.